# How do I open up Sublime text editor in Ubuntu 18.04LTS?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, debian, sublime-text

I want to open **sublime** text editor in my **ubuntu18.04LTS** command prompt to access my work.

Comment: Not sure I misunderstood your question, but if all you want to achieve is to call `Sublime Text` from the terminal to open a particular file, you can use `subl` ... for me `which subl` gives `/usr/bin/subl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `subl <filename>`?!

To call Sublime Text from a terminal (assuming you are running in an X environment), you can use the `subl` command, which is a small shell script that executes the following under the hood.

```
exec /opt/sublime_text/sublime_text --fwdargv0 "$0" "$@"
```

---

For the sake of completeness. The goal turned out to be using `sublime` as the name on the command line. So I suggested using an alias in the shell.

Not all shells may have that facility, but since this is about Ubuntu, chances were that the OP wanted a solution that worked in Bash.

So

```
alias sublime=subl
```

would make it available under the desired name. Alternatively `alias sublime=$(which subl)`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for your time. I found a way already.

Comment: @AduonyeIwarimie if you found another way, you should write it up as an answer (which is perfectly fine to do here and even encouraged). This way others can learn from your findings.

Comment: Thanks for your time and input @0xC0000022L

Comment: Thanks for your help @0xC0000022L , I had to undo the link that I created and tried your suggestion and **BOOM!!!** it worked. You know excitement did allow me to implement your suggestion earlier but I finally did. Your suggestion is easier. Thanks so much,I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can access sublime-text from command-line in 18LTS or 19LTS by following these steps:

After installing sublime-text, you have to confirm the location of the sublime text using this command:

For 18LTS,

`which subl`
output--->  /usr/bin/subl

For 19LTS,

`which subl`
output--->  /snap/bin/subl

firstly, You need to know where the sublime-text that you installed is located on your computer.

My sublime-text is located here: `/usr/bin/subl` (for 18LTS)

Then you need to link it to a new path: `/usr/local/bin/sublime`

Run1. `echo $PATH`

**Expected Output**

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

To link the sublime-text you, use this command `ln -s`.

You will need administration (`sudo`) permission to be able to link because you are about to work with system files.

Run using-

secondly, link the original path to a new path like this:

Run2:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/subl /usr/local/bin/sublime
```

You will be Required to input password, go ahead and input your password and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

`usr/local/bin/sublime` is the new path that the sublime-test could be accessed from.

Thirdly, Navigate to your working area, where you stored the project you are working on. It could be Desktop or documents or any environment.

Run3: `cd Documents/test`

You can now open sublime-text from the command-line using:

Run4: `sublime .`

`.` will open all the files in that environment but to be more specific you can do this:

`sublime test`

Depending on where you are working from, the Run1. and Run2. would be applicable but the rest will depend on your working environment.

Comment: So the purpose was to make it accessible under the name `sublime` and you knew about `subl` all along? Because your question is anything but unambiguous about that ;) ... with some shells you could use `alias sublime=subl` to achieve the same.

Comment: I didn't know of ``subl`` all along, I had to watch some related videos then adapted what I watched to solve the problem.